# CSS Changing background colour of specific cell in table when hovering over it

Tags: css, css-tables

I have a table with three columns. I want to be able to change the formatting of only the third column when I hover over it.

I want to be able to combine

td:nth-child(3) {background-color: #ddd;}

and

td:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are after.

```css
td:hover:nth-child(1) {background-color: #f5f5f5;}
td:hover:nth-child(2) {background-color: #ff0000;}
td:hover:nth-child(3) {background-color: #ddd;}
```

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Give the cell a class name or an id.

```
td[id="your id"]{...}

td[id="your id"]:hover{background-color: #ddd;}
```